# Alias works in seeder class but not in repository class

Tags: php, laravel

I added LanguagesFacede:class to aliases in a Laravel config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => [ // 
    ...
    'Languages' => PeterColes\Languages\LanguagesFacade::class,
]
```

In SystemSettingsSeeder, I have no problem with the following line:

```
$languages = Languages::lookup();
```

In my repository class, I get an error. Which means it can't understand the alias and searches under same repository:

```
Class 'App\Repositories\Languages' not found
```

I tried **composer dump-autoload** and **php artisan config:clear**, no solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: namespacing ... your Repository class  has a defined namespace so you would have to alias/import the class you want to use that isn't in that namespace ... the seeder is not defined in a namespace so its referencing classes in the root namespace

Comment: Thank you, I solved with adding the class with use.

Answer (score 0):

Since the repository class is under a namespace, alias is not applicable here. (I didn't know this).

So I simply added the following line:

```
use PeterColes\Languages\LanguagesFacade AS Languages;
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: or just `use Languages;` since the class is aliased to the root namespace